Why the differenced at lag 12 time series of a SARIMA(0,0,0)(0,1,1)_12 model follow the MA(1) pattern with step 12?
I am trying to understand why the ACF of the seasonally differenced series reveals the AR of MA structure of the original series.
For example:
The following lines creates a SARIMA(0,0,0)(0,1,1)_12 time series
library(astsa)
ts.value = sarima.sim(D=1, sma=-0.6, S=12, n=200) 

A typical plot of such a series is as follows:

From the ACF plot, we recognize the 12-period of the series. The PACF plot verifies further this remark.
Now, the following lines computes the first seasonal difference of the same series
ts.value.D1 <- diff(ts.value, lag = 12, differences = 1)

The corresponding plot of the differenced series is as follows.

From the ACF plot of the 12-differenced series a significant autocorrelation at lag 12 is appear. Since we know that MA(1) models has a single non-zero ACF value, we conclude that the original series is from an SARIMA(0,0,0)(0,1,1)_12 model.
This behavior seems reasonable, however it is not clear for me the theory behind this observation.
That is, why the differenced at lag 12 time series of a SARIMA(0,0,0)(0,1,1)_12 model should follows the MA(1) pattern with step 12?
Notes:

Analogous remarks can be easily reported for AR(1) models.
I found a post with analogous remarks but no theoretical explanation is given.


SARIMA(0,0,0)(0,1,1)12 is obtained by cumulatively summing SARIMA(0,0,0)(0,0,1)12 for every of the 12 seasonal periods. Differencing undoes the cumulative summation. I hope it is clear why the latter model shows an MA(1) pattern with step 12.
To simplify: if there were 2 seasons instead of 12, you would have SARIMA(0,0,0)(0,1,1)2 which is a series where odd observations come from the first cumulative sum* and even ones from the second. Now generalize from 2 to 12.
*Cumulative sum of the first season's values of SARIMA(0,0,0)(0,0,1)2

Thank you for your time and effort. I am trying to understand it algebraically. So if $X_t$ ​~ SARIMA(0, 0, 0)(0, 1, 1)12 then $Y_t = X_t ​- X_{t-12} ​= w_t + Θw_{t-12}$.  So, $Y_t  - Y_{t-12} = w_t – w_{t-12} + Θ(w_{t-12} – w_{t-24}) = w’t + Θw’{t-12}$ and the last equation is the $ΜΑ(1)_{12}$ equation ($w’t  = w_t  - w{t-12} ~ Ν(0, 2σ^2)$ since $w_t$, iid N(0, $σ^2$)). However, I am not sure that this argument is correct. Is it possible to provide more details?
